# How to compute (10mod42)(17mod42)^-1

Tags: modular-arithmetic, integers

Not sure how to tackle this problem since it involves an modular inverse and if I try to treat it as a division, it gives a non-integer solution.

Comment: The inverse of 17 mod 42 is a integer $x$ such that $17 \cdot x = 1$ (mod $42$). You can find such an inverse by finding a [Bézout's relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity) between 17 and 42.

Comment: Using $(17\bmod 42)^{-1}$ to denote $17^{-1}\bmod 42$ is abuse of notation. $\bmod$ is a modulo (remainder) operation ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)), so strictly speaking $(17\bmod 42)^{-1}=\frac{1}{17}$.

Answer (score 1):

First, the definition: $17^{-1}\equiv x\pmod {42}\iff 17x\equiv 1\pmod{42}$.

$17^{-1}\bmod {42}$ exists if and only if $\gcd(17,42)=1$, which is true here.

To find $17^{-1}\bmod 42$, you can use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm.

Subtract consecutive equations:

$$42=(1)(42)+(0)(17)\\17=(0)(42)+(1)(17)\\8=(1)(42)+(-2)(17)\\1=(-2)(42)+(5)(17)$$

Therefore $(5)(17)\equiv 1\pmod{42}$, so $17^{-1}\equiv 5\pmod{42}$.

Therefore $10\cdot 17^{-1}\equiv 10\cdot 5\equiv 8\pmod{42}$.

Answer (score 0):

Note:
$17*5=85=84+1=42*2+1$

Thus $(17)^{-1}\equiv5 \mod 42$